# How to allow duplicate-recipients for a given DocuSign Envelope?

Tags: docusignapi

We need our signers to be able to change signing method, i.e. to change from embedded signing to e-mail signing and vice versa.  The difference is marked, essentially, by the presence/absence of the recipients.signers.clientUserId attribute, and, to my knowledge, the REST API does not accommodate this as a change *per se*.

So, in order to change the signing method, I had to do an add/drop.  (Note that doing the drop first could disrupt the routing order, e.g. if I drop the remaining user in routing order 1, the envelope will immediately move on to routing order 2... so the add must occur first.)  I maintain a suffix to distinguish between instances of the signer during this type of change.  A recipient may start out with recipientId 100; upon changing signing method he becomes 101, and so on.  Tabs have to be added separately to the "new" user, 101, and then the "old" user, 100, is dropped.

This method has been working for several months.  Of late, however, we are receiving a duplicate-recipient error on the add.

On the other hand, we used to get an error if starting an envelope with duplicate signers, and now we don't.

Has anyone else experienced a change in the duplicate-recipient error?

Comment: Perhaps the person who voted down the question could explain what is unclear.

Comment: There is an account setting that you wouldn't be able to see that administrates the allowing of duplicate recipients. That sounds like it needs to be enabled. Without a sample of what you're submitting, it's really hard to actually answer your question. I did not downvote, but that's what I'm assuming was the reason for that.

Comment: Aha! And yet you were able to offer helpful information, i.e. that there is an account setting that I wouldn't be able to see... That gives me something to look for. Thank you!

Comment: Actually I was wrong, Whops!!! You want to declare allowRecipientRecursion in your call [Info Here](https://10226ec94e53f4ca538f-0035e62ac0d194a46695a3b225d72cc8.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/rest-api-guide-v2.pdf#page=103)

Comment: That looked quite promising; alas, I still got the duplicate-recipient error after adding allowRecipientRecursion" : "Yes" in my JSON create-envelope request.

Answer (score 0):

Andrew has correctly answered this in the comments section but adding here for the benefit of the community.  As mentioned, you need to set a property in your JSON (or XML) request to allow for duplicate recipients in the same envelope.  The property you need to set in your envelope definition is:

```
{ 
    "allowRecipientRecursion": "true"
}
```

API documentation regarding this property can be found [here](https://10226ec94e53f4ca538f-0035e62ac0d194a46695a3b225d72cc8.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/rest-api-guide-v2.pdf#page=103).  (Note that the actual property is listed one page down on page 104)

Comment: Ah! Context switch: "true" not "Yes". So many syntaxes to keep straight. Unfortunately, adding allowRecipientRecursion" : "true" in my JSON create-envelope request had no effect, i.e. I still get a duplicate-recipient error when I add the recipient with a different recipientId.

Comment: DocuSign Enterprise Support alludes to "a change in our most recent 
release," but it's not clear exactly what the change was.